# Organizing a multi-index by correct day

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Let's say I have an e-commerce, and I wanted to do a monthly analysis for total orders on a given day. I want to create a calendar like data frame for the month of March.

I tried creating a pivot table from my original dataframe by:

```
df1 = df

df1['Week'] = df1.order.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%W'))
df1['Day'] = df.groupby(level=0)['order'].max().apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%a-%D'))
df1 = df1.groupby(['cohort','cohort_group']).agg({'order_id': ['count']})
df1
```

But for some reason when I do that the dates go out of order.

```
                                 Orders
Week        Day                  
01      Fri-10/03/16               195
        Sat-10/04/16               186
        Sun-10/05/16               244
        Thu-10/02/16               169
        Wed-10/01/16               181
02      Fri-10/10/16               210
        Mon-10/06/16               161
        Sat-10/11/16               202
        Sun-10/12/16               259
        Thu-10/09/16               194
        Tue-10/07/16               168
        Wed-10/08/16               169
...
```

and so on.

I was going to use .unstack on the pivot table to replicate a calendar for March, but since the Day's are out of order it just improperly formats.

Is there a way to reorganize the days after it's been aggregated into a multi-index, or is there a better way to create a pivot table?

## EDIT:

So I took Alollz advice and formatted [day] with dt.dayofweek instead of strftime:

```
df1 = df

df1['Week'] = df1.order.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%W'))
df1['Day'] = df1.order.dt.dayofweek + 1
df1 = df1.groupby(['Week','Day']).agg({'dorder_id': ['count']})
df1unstack = df1.unstack()
```

and it got something I can unstack into what I want it too.

```
Day             1      2        3         4       5       6       7
Week                            
39             NaN     NaN    181.0     169.0    195.0  186.0   244.0
40            161.0   168.0   169.0     194.0    210.0  202.0   259.0
41            169.0   172.0   194.0     167.0    183.0  251.0   296.0
42            182.0   163.0   163.0     161.0    239.0  209.0   320.0
43            172.0   210.0   179.0     215.0    NaN    NaN     NaN
```

This is really close, but the only problem is that each date is off by one. is there a way to shift it over by one?

Comment: Well it is sorting, just that since they are strings it's alphabetical. Why not keep the `'Day'` as a `datetime64` with `pd.to_datetime()` and then if you ever need to figure out what day of the week it is you can just use the `datetime` attribute `.dt.weekday`

Comment: Hey thanks for cleaning up my post, and for pointing that out. I didn't bother to check that. I mainly need it shaped in the form of a calendar for presentation, and if I do it that way, it will date each day, which won't unstack in a clean way. Is there a way to number each day of the week from 0(sunday)-6(saturday)? so the first observation will start with 3(wednesday)?

Comment: @ALollz you were right, that solved the problem for the most part.